# npm override not fixing vulnerability

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-fetch, npm-audit

This is my vulnerability report :

High            node-fetch is vulnerable to Exposure of Sensitive
Information to an Unauthorized Actor

Package         node-fetch

Patched in      >=2.6.7

Dependency of   react-table-drag-select

Path            react-table-drag-select > react > fbjs > isomorphic-fetch >
node-fetch

More info       https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-r683-j2x4-v87g

I tried to fix it using overrride in my package.json

```
{
   "overrides":{
      "isomorphic-fetch":{
         "node-fetch":"2.6.7"
      }
   }
}
```

I have even tried

```
 {
   "overrides":{
      "react-table-drag-select":{
         "react":{
            "fbjs":{
               "isomorphic-fetch":{
                  "node-fetch":"latest"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I'm still getting the same vulnerability

Comment: To confirm, npm added support for overrides after version 8.3 are you sure you're using the right version?

Comment: You are very much right. I had to update the npm version